# Triple dots in GDB backtrace

Tags: gdb

My backtrace includes this line:

```
#2  z_swap (key=..., lock=0x2000ab90 <lock>) at /zephyr/kernel/include/kswap.h:145
#3  z_pend_curr (lock=lock@entry=0x2000ab90 <lock>, key=key@entry=..., wait_q=wait_q@entry=0x20017ff0 <spi_3_data+28>, timeout=timeout@entry=-1)
```

What does `key=...` and `key=key@entry=...` mean here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing `...` could mean is that those arguments are not scalars.

```
'set print frame-arguments VALUE'
     This command allows to control how the values of arguments are
     printed when the debugger prints a frame (*note Frames::).  The
     possible values are:

     'all'
          The values of all arguments are printed.

     'scalars'
          Print the value of an argument only if it is a scalar.  The
          value of more complex arguments such as arrays, structures,
          unions, etc, is replaced by '...'.  This is the default.  Here
          is an example where only scalar arguments are shown:

               #1  0x08048361 in call_me (i=3, s=..., ss=0xbf8d508c, u=..., e=green)
                 at frame-args.c:23

     'none'
          None of the argument values are printed.  Instead, the value
          of each argument is replaced by '...'.  In this case, the
          example above now becomes:

               #1  0x08048361 in call_me (i=..., s=..., ss=..., u=..., e=...)
                 at frame-args.c:23
```